# よろしくお願いします or ありがとうございます

Tags: word-choice, usage, politeness

I have to write a letter to my future Japanese host family. It's in English, but I want to end it in Japanese. Should I use よろしくお願いします or ありがとうございます or even どうぞよろしくおねがいします?

Answer (score 7):

Definitely よろしくお願いします or some variant thereof. よろしくお願いします type endings are common when you're thanking somebody *in advance*.

[This question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/820/what-is-wrong-with-ending-a-question-with-%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99) on meta on a similar topic might be interesting for you.

If you want to stick a simple Japanese phrase on the end of the letter, how about something like:

> ホームステイをとても楽しみにしています。どうぞよろしくお願いします。
>   I'm very much looking forward to the home-stay. Thank you for your kindness (in advance).

Or a bit more difficult (Japanese humble expression):

> いろいろとご迷惑をおかけすると思いますが、どうぞよろしくお願いします。
>   (Lit.) I might cause all kinds of bother for you, but thank you for your kindness (in advance).